# Does channel ratings (4.0.8) work with EE version 2.9.2?

Tags: devdemon, channel-ratings

I have channel ratings in place from dev demon (4.0.8) and running on EE 2.9.2, using the default code supplied in the docs as follows:

```
{exp:channel_ratings:rating_comment_avg entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <ul>
        <li>Value For Money: {rating:value_for_money:stars} ({rating:value_for_money:avg} of 5)</li>
         <li>Taste: {rating:taste:stars} ({rating:taste:avg} of 5)</li>
         <li>Quality: {rating:quality:stars} ({rating:quality:avg} of 5)</li>
         <li>OVERALL: {rating:overall:stars} ({rating:overall:avg} of 5)</li>
     </ul>
{/exp:channel_ratings:rating_comment_avg}

{exp:comment:form channel="products" rating:collection="products" entry_id="{entry_id}" dynamic="off" rating:enabled="yes"}
    {if rating:already_rated} You have already reviewed this product.{/if}
    {if rating:not_rated} 
         <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="{screen_name}" size="50" /><br />
         <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" value="{email}" size="50" /><br />      
        {rating:fields}
            <label>{rating:field_title}</label>
             <select name="{rating:form_name}">
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
         {/rating:fields}

        <label>Review</label>
         <textarea name="comment" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea> <br />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit Review">
    {/if}
{/exp:comment:form}
```

If I take out the variable "rating enabled=yes" from that form, the comments form renders perfectly. Once I put this in the form as above, I get no form rendered at all.

My channel allows comments (even said 'allow guests' for the laugh) and the form appears, and my admin panel renders the module information correctly, so I know my themes are in the right spot.

Am I missing something? If so, I would love a tip-off on what's wrong.

Edited for my comment below: I can enter information as a guest if I allow guests and I can rate items, but this is not showing up in my module's home page.

Comment: Have you tried adding rating:allow_guests="yes" to the form. Can you see the form if you are logged in? Also, make sure you do not have a channel field called "rating".

Comment: Yes, rating:allow_guests = yes renders the form alright, but I am logged in as super admin, so it shouldn't matter. Also the form wont appear when logged in and this is not set. I don't want guests to be able to do ratings, so how do I restrict this? There is no channel field or channel called rating.

Comment: So I have added a comment to the form and rated some fields for a product, but the admin panel doesn't show my rating at all. Rightly enough I can see the rating in the comments area for the entry, but what should I be seeing in the admin report area?  I have rating type comments ticked, and the channel ticked, but nothing is showing up in the module page. This is the page code I have:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view comment reviews in the Channel Ratings control panel you need to click on "Reviews". Please see screenshot.

[image]